# inequality $\frac{1}{1+3a}+\frac{1}{1+3b}+\frac{1}{1+3c}+\frac{1}{1+3d} \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, convex-analysis, fractions

Given real numbers $a, b, c, d$ with this condition: $$abcd=1$$
Let's prove this inequality: $$\frac{1}{1+3a}+\frac{1}{1+3b}+\frac{1}{1+3c}+\frac{1}{1+3d} \geq 1$$

Thank everybody!

Comment: If you want any help you have to show some work of your part.

Comment: Are this numbers positive? or not necessarily?

Comment: I see that inequality equal 1 when a=b=c=d=1 ! But I cannot prove this! Give me a suggestion

Comment: If $a=b=c=d=-1$, LHS $= -2 < 1=$ RHS.  You need to specify the domain.

Comment: Numbers a, b, c and d is positive :) and abcd = 1

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x ) = \frac{1}{1+3 e^x}$ is convex on $[\ln(\frac{1}{3}),\infty)$ look: [convexity proof.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281/%20%281%20%2b3e%5Ex%29%29%27%27)

Whenever $y\leq 1/3$ then we have that $\dfrac{1}{1+3y}   \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$, therefore whenever more than two of the $a,b,c,d$ are less than $1/3$ then the inequality holds. So, it remains to deal with the case that all $a,b,c,d$ are more  than $\frac{1}{3}$ or only one of them is less than $1/3$.

We now deal with the first case, and convexity gives 
$$ f(\ln a) + f(\ln b)+ f(\ln c)+f(\ln d) \geq 4 f\left( \frac{1}{4}\ln (abcd) \right) =4f(0)= 1$$

Now, for the second case assume that $d\leq 1/3$ and $a,b,c >1/3$. We use Jensen's again
$$ f(\ln a) + f(\ln b)+ f(\ln c) \geq 3 f\left( \frac{1}{3}\ln (abc) \right) =            3 f\left( \frac{1}{3}\ln (1/d) \right) = \frac{3}{1+3d^{-\frac{1}{3}}}$$

Hence, we need to show 
$$  \frac{1}{1+3d}+  \frac{3}{1+3d^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\geq 1  $$
This case is dealt in M. Roseberg's post.

Comment: @clark Your $f$ is not convex and your proof is wrong. See my proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In the comment section of the OP the author of this post specifies that $a,b,c,d$ are assumed to be positive, so what I have done here has taken into account this assumption

Comment: @clark But your $x$ can be negative.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you for you comment, now this is fixed and one case is using your argument.

Answer (score 2):

Given inequality is wrong. Try $a\rightarrow-\frac{1}{3}^-$.

For positive variables by Vasc's RCF Theorem it's enough to prove starting inequality for

$b=c=a$ and $d=\frac{1}{a^3}$, which gives $(a-1)^2(a+2)\geq0$.

Done!

Comment: it turns out that the convexity argument I used easily reduces the inequality to your case $a=b=c$ and $d=\frac{1}{a^3}$.

Comment: @clark Convexity gives that your $f$ is a convex function on $[0,+\infty)$, which says that we can use the RCF Theorem.

Comment: What I meant is if $d\leq 1/3$ then $\frac{1}{1+3d} \geq 1/2$ so assume, only one of the $a,b,c,d$ is less than $1/3$ otherwise we are done. So, $d \leq 3$  and $a,b,c,\geq 1/3$. Now $f$ is convex on $[   -\ln 3  , \infty    ]$ so we can apply jensen when for $a,b,c,\geq 1/3$.

Comment: @clark I think it's proof! You can post it.